# How do I loop through a table and click on the element

Tags: java, selenium

[image: ScreenShot]

How do I loop through a table and click on the element? I need to click on the highlighted class in the screen shot.

This is the code I have so far.

```
WebElement table1 = driver.findElement(By.className("rptDataOverlayPanelContent"));
List<WebElement> allrows1 = table1.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(WebElement row1: allrows1){
    List<WebElement> Cells = row1.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement Cell:Cells){
     if (Cell.getClass().equals("sp-preview-inner")) {
            Cell.click(); 
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  Help us help you by giving us all the information you can.  What is going wrong?  Where is it going wrong?  What don't you understand about this problem that is stopping you from solving it?

Comment: The code is not clicking on the element. Also I am not sure what does Cell.getClass() do ? Does it bring the value of the Class from the Html code.

Comment: I can tell you right off the bat that `.getClass()` is not part of selenium.  getClass() is getting into reflection, which lets a program analyze itself at runtime.  That isn't doing what you think it is.  `Cell.getClass()` returns a `Class<WebElement>` object, which is mostly useful for comparing against other Class<?> instances to see if two object references are of the same type.  Kinda like how you'd do `instanceof` except it would expect to class types to truly be the same type to pass

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable names should always start with a lower case character, so it's `cell` and `cells` instead.

Comment: @Zabuza I was about to say that lol, my comment about about getClass was all wrong because that capitalized object reference was throwing me for a loop

Comment: ah ok. Thanks. I am not sure how should I navigate to the class with the name "sp-preview-inner" and click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is `Cell.getClass()`. It doesn't return the Selenium related `class` property of DOM elements, it returns the **Java class**, so `Class<WebElement>` in this case. The method you are actually calling here is [Object#getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--).

To retrieve the DOM class property of a `WebElement` using Selenium you should use

```
cell.getAttribute("class") // Will return a String, like "sp-preview-inner"
```

instead. Here is the methods official [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-). And here's a relevant excerpt from it:

> Get the value of the given attribute of the element. Will return the current value, even if this has been modified after the page has been loaded.
>
> If the given name is "**class**", the "**className**" property is returned.

---

Alternatively you could directly search elements by class name:

```
// Find all div elements with class "sp-preview-inner"
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(
    By.cssSelector("div[class='sp-preview-inner']"));

// Click all of them
elements.forEach(WebElement::click);
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to click on the element.